# Magento Credit memo order items are not showing

Tags: magento

I am trying to create credit memo in magento but problem is, orders items are not showing in credit memo area.

This is order table in order area.
[image: this is order items table]

and this is credit memo table when i tried to create credit memo.
[image: this is credit memo table when i tried to create credit memo]

What can be problem. why it is not showing items on credit memo table,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you are using a module that overrides the credit memo table or logic.  See what happens if you comment/delete out most of the code in this file:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/creditmemo/create/items.phtml`

For example, change the first line of code from:

`<?php $_items = $this->getCreditmemo()->getAllItems() ?>`

to:

`<?php print "<h1>test</h1>"; var_dump($this->getCreditmemo()->getAllItems()); exit; ?>`

and remove all the rest. 
If you get nothing, not even the "test" string, then probably the template is overridden by some module and you should search for XML like this:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new>
                <file>xxxxxxxxx.xml</file>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

to find out what breaks the credit memo.